# activeConversation?.insertText doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, imessage

I have simple iMessage Extension with a table view. I try to use activeConversation to insert a text but when I tap on cell - nothing happens.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
    print(fullAppData[indexPath.row].title)

    self.activeConversation?.insertText(fullAppData[indexPath.row].title, completionHandler: nil)
}
```

Comment: post the code of cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: I found a solution for me. In my situation it doesn't work with Navigation Bar. If I delete a Navigation Bar from view - all works fine.

Comment: @user6023982 i need Navigation Bar, what should i do?